# How to add data off HTML page into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, html, scrape

How can I add data from a HTML page, into a MySQL Database based on the attributes?

It's already scraped data, but I would like to import  links into a particular field in a table and remove some things from them (ill work that out) and another from  into another field in a table.

I have PHP/MySQL and Linux. Should I use curl, and if so how do I actually add data into a MySQL DB?

Comment: Have you already made a table in your database for your scraped data to be inserted into?

Comment: Yes I have. I just need to work out how I can insert the data into it.

Comment: can you please give an example of how you want to store the links and the type of data you get you need to get them from?

Comment: The links are direct links to the store on which this product is from. These links just need to be stored as http://storename.com/product. I also need to import the a href...> text here </a> bit into another field (price). Its a tool to cache product prices weekly for easy use with other APIs/scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some PHP example to Insert and update data:

```
//***************************************   
// Connect to database
//
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','MyUserName','MyPassword',false,MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL|MYSQL_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
mysql_select_db('MyDatabase');

// If you work with UTF-8 it would be a good idea to set the character set as well to be sure.
//mysql_set_charset('utf8_general_ci');

//***************************************   
// Insert new data
//
$MyURL = mysql_real_escape_string("http://www.exampledomain.com/product/");
$Result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ProductTable (URLField) VALUES ('".$MyURL."')");
if($Result)
 print mysql_affected_rows();

//***************************************   
// Update existing data
//
$MyURL = mysql_real_escape_string("http://www.exampledomain.com/newproduct/");
$RecordID = 123;
$Result = mysql_query("UPDATE ProductTable SET URLField='".$MyURL."' WHERE ID=".$RecordID);
if($Result)
 print mysql_affected_rows();
```

Connect to the MySQL Server with [mysql_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and use [mysql_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) to select the database.
I'm not native English and use UTF-8 to get all the special character correct. If you have no need of this you can ignore this line.

All data that goes into a SQL server should be be sanitized, meaning escaping control characters such as quotes. The Variable $MyURL is sanitized with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before it is used in the SQL statement.

The SQL statement is executed with [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and returns true or false (for [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) statements). With [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) you can see how many rows that was affected by the SQL statement, a way to see if it worked as expected.

Next comes an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) example to change data in a single column and/or row. The $RecordID variable is the record ID you want to update (you need to know what record you want to update). This example is pinpointing a single record. By changing the WHERE clausule you can update a whole bunch of rows at the same time. For example

```
UPDATE ProductTable SET URLField='".$MyURL."' WHERE URLField='http://www.exampledomain.com/oldproduct/'
```

...will update all rows that have 'http://www.exampledomain.com/oldproduct/' in the field URLField.

I think this will get you going for a while...

Comment: I'm not that new to PHP/MySQL. Im after how I can parse a HTML file and then insert that parsed data into a MySQL field. I've setup a scraper, I just need to get the data off this scraper and into the database. It needs to be FULLY DYNAMIC. It will change every time someone enters a different query. FWIW: I've spent the last 2 hours trying to get a parser to work properly, but have failed. It will not parse the data and insert it into MySQL (SimpleXMLElement, PHP5) Yes its XHTML valid.

Comment: @Dean I'm sorry if the level was too low for you. The way I interpret your question is that you have already extracted the data and only wanted to know how to put it into a MySQL database. So if I understand you, you also need help with the actual extraction from the XHTML file as well. What are the attributes you are looking for? Or do you mean elements? What is failing in the SimpleXMLElement? Maybe you should update your question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

You will then use a MySQL query like "INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2) VALUES ('Testing','Testing 2')

Comment: I understand this bit of it, just not the bit on how I get the data.... I know how to insert it, just not get it.